# Review my edit of highly voted question on collection Size/Length

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I've made change to highly voted answer on a popular (50K views) question that is target of many duplicates - [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection). I would like to see if it is reasonable edit or other approach (new answer, new questions, don't use as duplicate target) should be used.

Edit (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/300540/revisions) essentially inlines some comments about "capacity" in addition to "length","count" and "size" already discussed in the post. I've considered adding new answer, but it would be mostly essentially duplicate that answer.

I understand that question itself *may* be considered off-topic/opinion-based, but it serves as duplicate target to many similar question and has high enough view count to deserve good non-opinion based answer. In particular I found that question when closing another one as duplicate of that one.

---

<sub>I will revert my change if there is enough disagreement with the edit.</sub>

Comment: If you don't change the intent of the answer and edit it like massively I think you're fine. Otherwise you can post your own answer and if OP doesn't like your edit he will roll it back :P

Comment: @Rizier123 sure, and there are enough existing discussions about it. I think my edit is *somewhat* borderline - I would not be worried making it on answer with less votes/views, but this is popular post and I'd like a bit more feedback/verification on particular edit (sort of unfortunate that one can't request review after passing 3K mark)

Comment: I'm torn about the edit. I think its good and that the author probably won't have a problem with it, but if I saw it in the suggested edit queue I'd reject it as an attempt to reply.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you're totally fine with it. Otherwise either wait 24h and see if  OP rolls it back or write a comment and then you can ask if OP is fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm cool with it - my original answer mainly took the 3 general methods I see in C++ code and the questioned specifically asked about, but I know there are many alternatives in different languages that boil down to the same things.

However, which mainstream language uses the Capacity() method?

If there aren't any, I think I'd remove it as a main entry and update the size() entry with a note about capacity instead.

Comment: Many collections in .Net have capacity as property(c#/vb.net/...). Also comment to the answer mentioned one of c++ collections. So I think separate entry for capacity is ok. Thanks for feedback /approval.